# How to use the created by column from SharePoint built-in fields?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting

How can I use the created by column from sharepoint built-in fields? (Sharepoint Online).

I'm designing a SharePoint document library and I want to use some of the built-in fields.

`[$FileLeafRef]` and `[$ID]` are working fine but the `[$Created_x0020_By]` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the **internal name** of SharePoint columns.

Internal name of created by field is `Author`. So try using `[$Author]` instead.

---

Check below URL to find out the internal name of any of your SharePoint columns:

[Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)